# How can I get the order before reactor flux sort

Tags: java, project-reactor, reactor

I have a list Like

`List<Mono<Integer>> numberMonos = new LinkedList();`

And I use this code to convert List<Mono> to Mono<List>,but the order was changed beacause of the concurrency.

`Flux.fromIterable(contentPlatformDetailDTOMonos).flatMap(x -> x).collectList();`

How can I get the order when I use this code to covert that before reactor flux sort.

Comment: flatMapSequential operator could work for this, it is still concurrent but keeps the order

Answer (score 1):

See a `concatMap()` operator instead: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#concatMap-java.util.function.Function-.

For the whole picture I repeat that JavaDoc over here:

```
/**
 * Transform the elements emitted by this {@link Flux} asynchronously into Publishers,
 * then flatten these inner publishers into a single {@link Flux}, sequentially and
 * preserving order using concatenation.
 * <p>
 * There are three dimensions to this operator that can be compared with
 * {@link #flatMap(Function) flatMap} and {@link #flatMapSequential(Function) flatMapSequential}:
 * <ul>
 *     <li><b>Generation of inners and subscription</b>: this operator waits for one
 *     inner to complete before generating the next one and subscribing to it.</li>
 *     <li><b>Ordering of the flattened values</b>: this operator naturally preserves
 *     the same order as the source elements, concatenating the inners from each source
 *     element sequentially.</li>
 *     <li><b>Interleaving</b>: this operator does not let values from different inners
 *     interleave (concatenation).</li>
 * </ul>
 *
 * <p>
 * Errors will immediately short circuit current concat backlog.
 *
 * <p>
 * <img class="marble" src="doc-files/marbles/concatMap.svg" alt="">
 *
 * <p><strong>Discard Support:</strong> This operator discards elements it internally queued for backpressure upon cancellation.
 *
 * @param mapper the function to transform this sequence of T into concatenated sequences of V
 * @param <V> the produced concatenated type
 *
 * @return a concatenated {@link Flux}
 */
public final <V> Flux<V> concatMap(Function<? super T, ? extends Publisher<? extends V>>
        mapper) {
```

Answer (score 0):

https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#concat-java.lang.Iterable-

> Concatenation is achieved by sequentially subscribing to the first source then waiting for it to complete before subscribing to the next, and so on until the last source completes.

According to The description the order is saved

```
Flux.concat(numberMonos).subscribe(System.out::println);
```